# Self sizing table view cell not resizing

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uistackview

I am trying to create a self sizing tableview cell with stack view, but the data get shrinked, is there any better way to achieve this.

[image]

For Stack view Distribution: Fill Proportionally

also I added tableview.estimatedRowHeight = 95, tableview.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension

Comment: The label you have put, it's number of lines is 0 ?

Comment: @Shivbaba'sson yes, I did

Comment: Can you try to change the stack view distribution property ?

Comment: @Shivbaba'sson after updating to fill it worked, thanks

Comment: Welcome, thank u